# Text direction adjustment in python-pptx

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I'm unable to control the text direction when text is embedded in a shape or a text box.

For example, the shape below is rotated 90 degrees, and the text is rotating with it as well, but I need it to appear normal, which is horizontal

[click here to see an image showing this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEKY2.png)

Any way to do this in pptx or otherwise?